# search the list of elements from the list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with my code. I want to search for the element in the list of arrays when I use this:

```
program_button = [elem.control for elem in self.program_buttons]
positions_X = list()
positions_Y = list()
for elem in program_button:
    positions_X.append(elem.getX())
    positions_Y.append(elem.getY())
posX = map(str, positions_X)
posY = map(str, positions_Y)

print posX
```

Here is the results:

```
19:42:50 T:2264  NOTICE: ['25', '375', '723', '1073', '1771', '2120', '2469']
```

I want to search the element `723` from the list.

Can you please show me an example of how I can search the element `723` from the list using the variable called `posX`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generator expression within `next` function :

```
>>> next((i for i in posX if i == '723'),None)
'723'
```

This will returns the variable you are searching if it exist or `None` if it doesn't.

And if you want to check the existence of this value you can just use `in` operand :

```
if `723` in Posx:
    #do stuff
```

And if you want to return the index you can use `list.index` method with a `try-except` statement for handling the `ValueError` or use `enumerate` within preceding script :

```
>>> next((i for i,j in enumerate(posX) if j == '723'),None)
2
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to get the index of the element `723` in the list you can use :

```
posX.index('723')
```

The below convenient function can be used if the item happens to not be in the list :

```
def search_item(L,item):
    try:
        return L.index(item)
    except ValueError:
        return -1
```

Call it with `print(search_item(posX,'723'))`which will return `2` in your case.
If the element is not foundable, the function will return -1.

Comment: thank you very much for this, how i can check the index of the element `723` using if statement?

Comment: Why would you want to do that ? I will edit my answer for additional code example

Comment: well i want to use it because i want to check if it return to true or not.

Comment: I disagree with the edited solution. It is inefficient, since it looks for the element twice. Edit it and call `posX.index` in a try/except to catch the exception.

Comment: well done now, I upvoted it. And yes, find is not a method available on a list, but on strings rather. My bad.